# Compiled javascript files (from typescript) get added to my Visual Studio project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

My Visual Studio project has Typescript files. We keep the Typescript files under version control but not the generated Javascript files. The problem is that whenever I change a Typescript file, the Javascript files get added to my solution. It's annoying because I have to manually remove them from the project before checking stuff in. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: What version of the TypeScript plugin are you using?

Comment: The plugin version is 0.8.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of the TypeScript plugin will easily solve your problem. There have been a LOT of changes since that version. But, for one, the default functionality is to NOT add the js files to the solution.